# How to get Summation using $this->db->select_sum and $this->db->group_by($groupBy) method

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I wanted to get summation of a column's value Grouping by another column using Codegniter framework. on model which name is action, i have used this method:

```
public function read_sum_groupby($table, $column,$groupBy,$where=array()){
    $this->db->group_by($groupBy); 
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->select_sum($column);
    $result = $this->db->get($table);

    return $result->result();
}
```

and then i called that method on view like this

```
$installment_discount = $this->action->read_sum_groupby("installment","discount","installment_id",array("loan_id"=>$loan->id));
```

and then i printed the output like this

```
<pre>
 <?php print_r($installment_discount); ?>    
</pre>
```

Result was

[image: This is the Print_r result]

you can see the last value is 800 but my expected was 200.

my table was

[image]

Comment: The result is what you would expect from the data you have given. You've asked the database to `group_by` `installment_id`. You have 7 different installment_id, so you have 7 results in your output. It's correctly added up the values of discount to get a total of 800. I'm not sure what you expected to be different?

Comment: There are 7 different installment_id and the last 4 installment_id are same. so i want the last 4 discount's sum for one time and they will be sum with another 6 discount like 0+0+0+0+0+0+200 = 200 @JoeMiller

Answer (score 0):

The installment_id of 11,12,13,14 rows are all 7759702. So if you group by installment_id then select_sum(discount), the sql will be like this:

```
SELECT sum(discount) FROM installment WHERE loan_id=1 GROUP BY installment_id;
```

the discount of 11,12,13,14 rows will sum up, so you get 800.

if you want to get 200, the sql should be this:

```
SELECT sum(distinct(discount)) FROM installment WHERE loan_id=1 GROUP BY installment_id;
```

your code can be written like this:

```
$this->db->select_sum("distinct($column)", $column);
```

Comment: try distinct(), sql select filed should be `sum(distinct(discount))` then you can get 200 @Maruf